# gstreamer: gstaggregator pad properties not working on gstreamer 1.0

Tags: gstreamer, glib, gstreamer-1.0

I have written a property for sink pads (e.g sink_0::new_property). It is showing as sink property when we are triggering gst-inspect-1.0 . But when it is calling from the pipeline getting an error like "WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no property "sink_1::new_property". I have found an API gst_type_mark_as_plugin_api in version 1.18.  Is it compulsory to invoke this or Is there any way to implement sink properties in Gstreamer 1.0.

```
.................Header file.........................................

#define GST_TYPE_EXAMPLEAGGEGATOR                 (gst_exampleaggregator_get_type())
#define GST_EXAMPLEAGGEGATOR(obj)                 (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST((obj), GST_TYPE_EXAMPLEAGGEGATOR, GstExampleAggregator))
#define GST_EXAMPLEAGGEGATOR_CLASS(klass)         (G_TYPE_CHECK_CLASS_CAST((klass), GST_TYPE_EXAMPLEAGGEGATOR, GstExampleAggregatorClass))
#define GST_IS_EXAMPLEAGGEGATOR(obj)              (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_TYPE((obj), GST_TYPE_EXAMPLEAGGEGATOR))
#define GST_IS_EXAMPLEAGGEGATOR_CLASS(klass)      (G_TYPE_CHECK_CLASS_TYPE((klass), GST_TYPE_EXAMPLEAGGEGATOR))

#define GST_TYPE_EXAMPLEAGGEGATOR_PAD             (gst_exampleaggregator_pad_get_type())
#define GST_EXAMPLEAGGEGATOR_PAD(obj)             (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST((obj), GST_TYPE_EXAMPLEAGGEGATOR_PAD, GstExampleAggregatorPad))
#define GST_EXAMPLEAGGEGATOR_PAD_CLASS(klass)     (G_TYPE_CHECK_CLASS_CAST((klass), GST_TYPE_EXAMPLEAGGEGATOR_PAD, GstExampleAggregatorPadClass))
#define GST_IS_EXAMPLEAGGEGATOR_PAD(obj)          (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_TYPE((obj), GST_TYPE_EXAMPLEAGGEGATOR_PAD))
#define GST_IS_EXAMPLEAGGEGATOR_PAD_CLASS(klass)  (G_TYPE_CHECK_CLASS_TYPE((klass), GST_TYPE_EXAMPLEAGGEGATOR_PAD))


typedef struct _GstExampleAggregator         GstExampleAggregator;
typedef struct _GstExampleAggregatorClass    GstExampleAggregatorClass;
typedef struct _GstExampleAggregatorPad      GstExampleAggregatorPad;
typedef struct _GstExampleAggregatorPadClass GstExampleAggregatorPadClass;

typedef struct _GstExampleAggregatorPadPrivate      GstExampleAggregatorPadPrivate;

struct _GstExampleAggregator
{
    GstAggregator parent;
};

struct _GstExampleAggregatorClass
{
    GstAggregatorClass parent_class;
};

struct _GstExampleAggregatorPad
{
    GstAggregatorPad parent;
    gint value;
};

struct _GstExampleAggregatorPadClass
{
    GstAggregatorPadClass parent_class;
};

GType gst_exampleaggregator_get_type (void);
GType gst_exampleaggregator_pad_get_type (void);


.......................Source file..........................


G_DEFINE_TYPE(GstExampleAggregator, gst_exampleaggregator, GST_TYPE_AGGREGATOR);
G_DEFINE_TYPE(GstExampleAggregatorPad, gst_exampleaggregator_pad, GST_TYPE_AGGREGATOR_PAD);


static void
gst_exampleaggregator_class_init(GstExampleAggregatorClass* instance)
{
    GObjectClass* gobject_class;
    GstElementClass* gstelement_class;

    gobject_class = (GObjectClass*) instance;
    gstelement_class = (GstElementClass*) instance;


    gst_element_class_set_details_simple(gstelement_class,
        "Compositor",
        "Video/Compositor",
        "Composite multiple video streams",
        "Author");

  gst_element_class_add_static_pad_template_with_gtype (gstelement_class,
      &src_factory, GST_TYPE_AGGREGATOR_PAD);
  gst_element_class_add_static_pad_template_with_gtype (gstelement_class,
      &sink_factory, GST_TYPE_EXAMPLEAGGEGATOR_PAD);

    gstelement_class->request_new_pad = gst_exampleaggregator_request_new_pad;
    gstelement_class->release_pad = gst_exampleaggregator_release_pad;

    instance->parent_class.aggregate = gst_exampleaggregator_aggregate;


    g_type_class_ref (GST_TYPE_EXAMPLEAGGEGATOR_PAD);
}



static void
gst_exampleaggregator_pad_class_init (GstExampleAggregatorPadClass* pad_class)
{

    GObjectClass* gobject_class = (GObjectClass *)pad_class;

    gobject_class->set_property = gst_exampleaggregator_pad_set_property;
    gobject_class->get_property = gst_exampleaggregator_pad_get_property;

    g_object_class_install_property (gobject_class, PROP_PAD_TEXT, g_param_spec_string("text", "text",
        "Text to be display.", NULL , (GParamFlags)(G_PARAM_READWRITE | GST_PARAM_CONTROLLABLE | G_PARAM_STATIC_STRINGS)));
        
}


static void
gst_exampleaggregator_pad_init(GstExampleAggregator* filter)
{

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a code block that shows how you're installing the property and where you actually set it?

Comment: Added the code snippet